# setSize function creating confusion

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This code runs quite nicely. But when I put `setSize(700,700)` and run the code, it does not show me  the JButtons but the frame only. I thought that there might be some problem with the grid layouts of the JButtons, so I changed the last two entries of every gridlayout to, say `GridLayout(3,1,300,300)`. However, the result is same (i.e. no JButtons are visible). Why is it happening?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Calculator extends JFrame
{
    JButton jb[]=new JButton[12];
    public Calculator(String title)
    {
    super(title);
    Container c;
    c=getContentPane();
    setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
    Panel p1=new Panel();
    for(int h=0;h<9;h++)
    {jb[h]=new JButton(""+(h+1));}
    jb[9]=new JButton("=");
    jb[10]=new JButton(".");
    jb[11]=new JButton("0");
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,3,3));
    for(int h=0;h<12;h++){p1.add(jb[h]);}

    Panel p2=new Panel(new GridLayout(3,1,3,3));
    JButton jb1[]=new JButton[3];
    jb1[0]=new JButton("+");
    jb1[1]=new JButton("-");
    jb1[2]=new JButton("*");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    p2.add(jb1[i]);}


    Panel p4=new Panel(new GridLayout(3,1,3,3));
    JButton jb4[]=new JButton[3];
     jb4[0]=new JButton("%");
     jb4[1]=new JButton("/");
    jb4[2]=new JButton("-");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    p4.add(jb4[i]);}

    Panel p3=new Panel();
    JLabel jl0=new JLabel("INPUT:");
    TextField tf=new TextField(30);
    p3.add(tf);
    p3.add(jl0);    
    jl0.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    c.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,p1);
    c.add(BorderLayout.EAST,p2);
    c.add(BorderLayout.WEST,p4);
    c.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,p3);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {new Calculator("Lets calculate ! :)");}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the setVisible(true) on the end of the method (after adding the buttons).

Comment: so...setVisible(true) was making the frame visible and not the buttons ? But when setSize(100,100) with GridLayout(3,1,3,3) , the buttons were not visible but become visible once I maximise it .Why don't they remain invisible ? And on maximising the window the buttons changed their size on their own .But in case of setSize(700,700) ,on minimising they  become visible ? Why so ?

Comment: thats what I told in my ans, your setSize had invalidated the component hierarchy of jFrame, the resize event validates it again, so the buttons became visible again.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `setSize(100, 100);` which creates a very small window. Instead, use `pack();` in the end of your constructor to fit the frame to your panels.

Comment: yea..that gave me a cool output ! :)  But I had to use show(); also in order to display the GUI . pack();  is only biding the data . But, thanks! I got a new thing to learn (i.e. pack()) .

Answer (score 1):

because `setSize()` invalidates the component hierarchy, ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29

you need to re validate it.

for that you can call  `revalidate();` or even `setVisible(true)` again in the end.

its better to call `pack();` and then `setVisible(true);` in the end instead of calling `setVisible()` before adding any components to your jframe.